Updating a MutableStateFlow<List<object>> Maintaining References of StateFlow in the object
I'm working with Kotlin's StateFlow to manage a list of User objects which holds a StateFlow reference to a instance of UserDetail objects.
These two classes have to be separeted for some reason.
data class User(val id: String, val name: String /* ...*/) { lateinit var userFlow: StateFlow<UserDetail> } 
data class UserDetail (val id: String, var value: String /* ...*/)

The UserDetail instances are managed within a Repository using a MutableMap<String, UserDetail>.
These instances are dynamically modified and need to be reflected in the User objects.
At the same time, changes to the User instances alse need to be detectable via List<MutableStateFlow<User>>.
So I wrote the code like below.
@Singleton
class UserRepository @Inject constructor() {
  // key is User.id
  private val _userDetails = mutableMapOf<String, MutableStateFlow<UserDetail>>()

  private fun createUserDetail() { /* ... */ }

  private fun injectUserDetail(user: User) {
    user.userFlow = _userDetails[user.id]
    return user
  }

  private fun updateUserDetail(newValue: String) {
    _userDetails.get[user.id]?.update { current -> current.copy(value=newValue) }
  }
}

@HiltViewModel
class UserViewModel @Inject constructor(private val userRepository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {
  private val _userFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<User>>(emptyList())
  val userFlow: StateFlow<List<User>> = _userFlow

  fun newUserArrived(id:String, name: String) {
    val user = User(id, name)
    _userFlow.update { currentList -> /* I want to add (userRepository.injectUserDetail(user)) */ }
  } 
}

I think the problem is this part.
_userFlow.update { /* ... */ }

Because updating a MutableStateFlow requires creating a new list, I believe the references to the MutableMap<String, MutableStateFlow<User>> are lost here.
Could you please tell me if there is a way to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Lots of your code seems to got corrupted while creating the example code. Please create a new project and copy the code from the question there and fix all the compile errors. Then you can [edit] the question and replace the current code with the fixed code. -- That said, please also explain in more detail why _userFlow.update { it + userRepository.injectUserDetail(user) } does not work as expected. Please construct an example where this fails to do what you want and also add it to the question.
